# Sticky Header is hide on half page on smartphone

Tags: css, wordpress

i have this weird issue that dont have idea how to resolve myself. On my [site](http://www.zineki.com) when load on smartphone, sticky header is showed but when start to scroll to bottom, its hide and not show again, until you back to top. Sticky header is hide somewhere on half of page when scroll to bottom. Is possible to make it to show when scroll to bottom? i think that this is CSS that control that part:

```
#page:not(.vertical-header) #site-header.fixed {
width: 100%;
position: static;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

i tryed to change `position: static;` to `position: fixed;` but dont seems to make change on layout. Help?

**EDIT:** One member suggested that header is hidding in this code somewhere:

```
if (this.isResponsive && !this.$wrapper.hasClass('sticky-header-on-mobile')) {
            if (!$('.mobile-menu-slide-wrapper.opened').length && !$('#primary-menu.dl-menuopen').length && !$('.menu-overlay.active').length) {
                if (scrollY - this.oldScrollY > 0 && scrollY > 300 && !this.$el.hasClass('hidden')) {
                    self.$el.addClass('hidden');
                }

                if (scrollY - this.oldScrollY < 0 && 
 this.$el.hasClass('hidden')) {
                    self.$el.removeClass('hidden');
                }
            } else {
                self.$el.removeClass('hidden');
            }
        }
```

I tryed to modify `scrollY > 300` to `scrollY > 500` but dont notice changes. Header is still hidding.

Comment: You have javascript that is adding class `hidden` to the `sticky-header` on mobile once you scroll to a certain point.
`thegem-header.js` lines 206-218

Comment: Why do you need that code at all? You said you want it to be visible all the way to the bottom. If you just remove that entire block of code it should work just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to put jmulder5's answer here:

Remove these lines of code from ./wp-content/themes/thegem/thegem-hearder.js (206-218):

```
if (this.isResponsive && !this.$wrapper.hasClass('sticky-header-on-mobile')) {
                if (!$('.mobile-menu-slide-wrapper.opened').length && !$('#primary-menu.dl-menuopen').length && !$('.menu-overlay.active').length) {
                    if (scrollY - this.oldScrollY > 0 && scrollY > 300 && !this.$el.hasClass('hidden')) {
                        self.$el.addClass('hidden');
                    }
                if (scrollY - this.oldScrollY < 0 && this.$el.hasClass('hidden')) {
                    self.$el.removeClass('hidden');
                }
            } else {
                self.$el.removeClass('hidden');
            }
        }
```